# Incremental/Decremental value function Localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage

I made an incremental and a decremental function for a form value. For now, with local variables, everything goes well.

But how can I now made it work so that the value goes saved in the Localstorage? And how can i retrieve it after, and call it whenever I need it, also in other pages, f.e. to use as game-score?

Already tried many times, alone a solution to find, and nothing worked.

```
<form id="score">
   <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue3()" value="+60" />
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue2()" value="+30" />
  </form>

<script>

function incrementValue3()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value = value + 60;
    document.getElementById("number").value = value;
};

function incrementValue2()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value = value + 30;
    document.getElementById("number").value = value;
};

</script>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, where and how do you want to use localStorage? Please also read through the documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: Where: In the "value" section of the form. How: as a point-counter for a game.

Comment: Like: i click a button -> score goes up to 30pts. Then, i click another button, in another page, score is retrieved from Localstorage and the 30pts from before are now added to other 20pts.

Answer (score 1):

For storing a value in localStorage, use the following line of code :

```
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value, 10);
localStorage.setItem("value", value);
```

To use the value somewhere user

```
localStorage.getItem("value");
```

For your use case:

```
document.getElementById("result").value = localStorage.getItem("value");
```

Please refer to the documentation for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @Javanoob87 Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: I will try it. I will give a feedback on it if it's working inside the form as i need (with the increment and decrement thing that i need). Thanks for now.

Comment: It almos worked. But just one time. Then there's no increment, and whenever i click to add a value (+30 or +60) it refresh to the one-single-time incremented value of the form.